# Correct use of preposition before 'contempt'

Tags: prepositions

Is it correct to say:

> They looked at us with contempt?

Or should we say:

> They looked at us in contempt?

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is correct to use **with**, although you could say that they **looked at you in a contemptuous manner**.

**In contempt** is a legal expression, used when some person/organisation is said to **be in contempt of court**.

It is also the name of a TV show.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contempt_of_court
https://www.ourfamilywizard.com/blog/contempt-what-does-mean-family-court